# Trying to get images to link to items in a selection list so that when you select one option the corresponding image will appear using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<td class="inputcell">
    <select name="prod" id="prod">
        <option value="0">Products from Sports World</option>
        <option value="50.00">Jersey ($50.00)</option>
        <option value="45.50">Boots ($45.50)</option>
        <option value="7.50">Gloves ($7.50)</option>
        <option value="20.00">Tennis Rackets ($20.00)</option>
        <option value="50.00">Golf club ($50.00)</option>
        <option value="5.00">Swimming hat ($5.00)</option>
    </select>
```

this is the selection list that I would like to have images appear when you select an item. e.g. a picture of a jersey appears when you select the jersey option. thanks.

Comment: So try.. i can't see any javascript code? This is not a place like "do this job for me" you should have tried something. Now there is just one select field..

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. I have tried I have some JavaScript code but it's not even close. Just looking for any help in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i help you to get started. You can use JQuery to check for 
changes in that Select list.

Add id:s to your options like:

```
<option id="product1" value="50.00">Jersey ($50.00)</option>
<option id="product2" value="45.50">Boots ($45.50)</option>
etc..
```

javasctipt:

```
// Make product list in javascript
var products = [];

products.push({id:"product1", image:"images/some.png"});
products.push({id:"product2", image:"images/some.png"});
// etc..

// When product changes..
$('#prod').on('change', function() {

  // Get selected product id from <option> element
  var selected_id = $(this).attr('id');

  // Loop products
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    // Check if id is same as selected..
    if (products[i].id == selected_id) {
      // Change image element source to match product image..
      $('#product_image').attr('src', products[i].image);
      break;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I'm gonna try that now hopefully i get it working. thanks

Comment: i must seem very stupid but is there a way of making the image appear on the website. i have the javascript in one file and the html in another file. maybe its just not linking correctly ? and advice would be great.thanks

Comment: @user3091082 please try to learn some basics before asking questions.. just put <img id="product_image" src="imagefilename" /> in your html..